# Hibernate entites relation

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to make a small invoicing system using Spring, Hibernate, so I built three domain classes (Product), (InvoiceMaster) and (InvoiceDetails), now I am a bit confused about the relationship between (InvoiceDetails) and (Product), in (InvoiceDetails) I have added products as:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID", nullable=false)
private Product product;
```

but then I found many online examples which describe the relation as @OneToOne so I am confused should the relation be as @OneToOne or @ManyToOne?!

From my understanding it is many invoice details records for one product, so it should be Many to One, please advice

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneToOne means: a product only has one (or zero) invoice detail, and an invoice detail concerns one (or zero) product.

My guess is that you can have several invoice details for the same product (because you'll sell many copies of a product to various customers), so the association should be a ManyToOne.

Answer (score 1):

If one `Product` can be used in several `InvoiceDetails`, you should use `@ManyToOne`, otherwise use `@OneToOne`.

Just from my own experience, `@ManyToOne` is more flexible than `@OneToOne` in terms of queries optimization.